# Why is the arrow hitting the player? Minecraft Modding 1.8

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to develop a mod for Minecraft using the Minecraft Forge 1.8 library. For my mod, I have decided to create my own custom arrows that fire from my custom crossbow. After putting my Item, Entity and Render classes for the arrow, I have found that the arrow keeps on hitting the player nevertheless it is thrown. I have tried to implement `IThrowableEntity` and did a debug check for the shooter of the arrow, but I can't find out the problem.

Here's the code:
onUpdate() from the EntityArrow class:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate() {
    if (this.prevRotationPitch == 0.0F && this.prevRotationYaw == 0.0F)
    {
        float f = MathHelper.sqrt_double(this.motionX * this.motionX + this.motionZ * this.motionZ);
        this.prevRotationYaw = this.rotationYaw = (float)(Math.atan2(this.motionX, this.motionZ) * 180.0D / Math.PI);
        this.prevRotationPitch = this.rotationPitch = (float)(Math.atan2(this.motionY, (double)f) * 180.0D / Math.PI);
    }

    BlockPos blockpos = new BlockPos(this.xTile, this.yTile, this.zTile);
    IBlockState iblockstate = this.worldObj.getBlockState(blockpos);
    Block block = iblockstate.getBlock();

    if (block.getMaterial() != Material.air)
    {
        block.setBlockBoundsBasedOnState(this.worldObj, blockpos);
        AxisAlignedBB axisalignedbb = block.getCollisionBoundingBox(this.worldObj, blockpos, iblockstate);

        if (axisalignedbb != null && axisalignedbb.isVecInside(new Vec3(this.posX, this.posY, this.posZ)))
        {
            this.inGround = true;
        }
    }

    if (this.arrowShake > 0)
    {
        --this.arrowShake;
    }

    if (this.inGround)
    {
        int j = block.getMetaFromState(iblockstate);

        if (block == this.inTile && j == this.inData)
        {
            ++this.ticksInGround;

            if (this.ticksInGround >= 1200)
            {
                this.setDead();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.inGround = false;
            this.motionX *= (double)(this.rand.nextFloat() * 0.2F);
            this.motionY *= (double)(this.rand.nextFloat() * 0.2F);
            this.motionZ *= (double)(this.rand.nextFloat() * 0.2F);
            this.ticksInGround = 0;
            this.ticksInAir = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ++this.ticksInAir;
        Vec3 vec31 = new Vec3(this.posX, this.posY, this.posZ);
        Vec3 vec3 = new Vec3(this.posX + this.motionX, this.posY + this.motionY, this.posZ + this.motionZ);
        MovingObjectPosition movingobjectposition = this.worldObj.rayTraceBlocks(vec31, vec3, false, true, false);
        vec31 = new Vec3(this.posX, this.posY, this.posZ);
        vec3 = new Vec3(this.posX + this.motionX, this.posY + this.motionY, this.posZ + this.motionZ);

        if (movingobjectposition != null)
        {
            vec3 = new Vec3(movingobjectposition.hitVec.xCoord, movingobjectposition.hitVec.yCoord, movingobjectposition.hitVec.zCoord);
        }

        Entity entity = null;
        List list = this.worldObj.getEntitiesWithinAABBExcludingEntity(this, this.getEntityBoundingBox().addCoord(this.motionX, this.motionY, this.motionZ).expand(1.0D, 1.0D, 1.0D));
        double d0 = 0.0D;
        int i;
        float f1;

        for (i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        {
            Entity entity1 = (Entity)list.get(i);

            if (entity1.canBeCollidedWith() && (entity1 != this.shootingEntity || this.ticksInAir >= 100)){
            {
                f1 = 0.3F;
                AxisAlignedBB axisalignedbb1 = entity1.getEntityBoundingBox().expand((double)f1, (double)f1, (double)f1);
                MovingObjectPosition movingobjectposition1 = axisalignedbb1.calculateIntercept(vec31, vec3);

                if (movingobjectposition1 != null)
                {
                    double d1 = vec31.distanceTo(movingobjectposition1.hitVec);

                    if (d1 < d0 || d0 == 0.0D)
                    {
                        entity = entity1;
                        d0 = d1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (entity != null)
        {
            movingobjectposition = new MovingObjectPosition(entity);
        }

        if (movingobjectposition != null && movingobjectposition.entityHit != null && movingobjectposition.entityHit instanceof EntityPlayer)
        {
            EntityPlayer entityplayer = (EntityPlayer)movingobjectposition.entityHit;

            if (entityplayer.capabilities.disableDamage || this.shootingEntity instanceof EntityPlayer && !((EntityPlayer)this.shootingEntity).canAttackPlayer(entityplayer))
            {
                movingobjectposition = null;
            }
        }

        float f2;
        float f3;
        float f4;

        if (movingobjectposition != null)
        {
            if (movingobjectposition.entityHit != null)
            {
                f2 = MathHelper.sqrt_double(this.motionX * this.motionX + this.motionY * this.motionY + this.motionZ * this.motionZ);
                int k = MathHelper.ceiling_double_int((double)f2 * this.damage);

                if (this.getIsCritical())
                {
                    k += this.rand.nextInt(k / 2 + 2);
                }

                DamageSource damagesource;

                if (this.shootingEntity == null)
                {
                    damagesource = causeFlingDamage(this, this);
                }
                else
                {
                    damagesource = causeFlingDamage(this, this.shootingEntity);
                }

                if (this.isBurning() && !(movingobjectposition.entityHit instanceof EntityEnderman))
                {
                    movingobjectposition.entityHit.setFire(5);
                }

                if (movingobjectposition.entityHit.attackEntityFrom(damagesource, (float)k))
                {
                    if (movingobjectposition.entityHit instanceof EntityLivingBase)
                    {
                        EntityLivingBase base = (EntityLivingBase)movingobjectposition.entityHit;

                        if (!this.worldObj.isRemote)
                        {
                            base.setArrowCountInEntity(base.getArrowCountInEntity() + 1);


                        if (this.knockbackStrength > 0)
                        {
                            f4 = MathHelper.sqrt_double(this.motionX * this.motionX + this.motionZ * this.motionZ);

                            if (f4 > 0.0F)
                            {
                                movingobjectposition.entityHit.addVelocity(this.motionX * (double)this.knockbackStrength * 0.6000000238418579D / (double)f4, 0.1D, this.motionZ * (double)this.knockbackStrength * 0.6000000238418579D / (double)f4);
                            }
                        }

                        if (this.shootingEntity instanceof EntityLivingBase)
                        {
                            EnchantmentHelper.func_151384_a(base, this.shootingEntity);
                            EnchantmentHelper.func_151385_b((EntityLivingBase)this.shootingEntity, base);
                        }

                        if (this.shootingEntity != null && movingobjectposition.entityHit != this.shootingEntity && movingobjectposition.entityHit instanceof EntityPlayer && this.shootingEntity instanceof EntityPlayerMP)
                        {
                            ((EntityPlayerMP)this.shootingEntity).playerNetServerHandler.sendPacket(new S2BPacketChangeGameState(6, 0.0F));
                        }
                    }

                    this.playSound("random.bowhit", 1.0F, 1.2F / (this.rand.nextFloat() * 0.2F + 0.9F));


                    if (!(movingobjectposition.entityHit instanceof EntityEnderman)){
                        this.worldObj.setBlockState(getPosition(), Blocks.hardened_clay.getDefaultState());
                        this.setDead();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.motionX *= -0.10000000149011612D;
                    this.motionY *= -0.10000000149011612D;
                    this.motionZ *= -0.10000000149011612D;
                    this.rotationYaw += 180.0F;
                    this.prevRotationYaw += 180.0F;
                    this.ticksInAir = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                BlockPos blockpos1 = movingobjectposition.getBlockPos();
                this.xTile = blockpos1.getX();
                this.yTile = blockpos1.getY();
                this.zTile = blockpos1.getZ();
                iblockstate = this.worldObj.getBlockState(blockpos1);
                this.inTile = iblockstate.getBlock();
                this.inData = this.inTile.getMetaFromState(iblockstate);
                this.motionX = (double)((float)(movingobjectposition.hitVec.xCoord - this.posX));
                this.motionY = (double)((float)(movingobjectposition.hitVec.yCoord - this.posY));
                this.motionZ = (double)((float)(movingobjectposition.hitVec.zCoord - this.posZ));
                f3 = MathHelper.sqrt_double(this.motionX * this.motionX + this.motionY * this.motionY + this.motionZ * this.motionZ);
                this.posX -= this.motionX / (double)f3 * 0.05000000074505806D;
                this.posY -= this.motionY / (double)f3 * 0.05000000074505806D;
                this.posZ -= this.motionZ / (double)f3 * 0.05000000074505806D;
                this.playSound("random.bowhit", 1.0F, 1.2F / (this.rand.nextFloat() * 0.2F + 0.9F));
                this.inGround = true;
                this.arrowShake = 7;
                this.setIsCritical(false);

                if (this.inTile.getMaterial() != Material.air)
                {
                    this.inTile.onEntityCollidedWithBlock(this.worldObj, blockpos1, iblockstate, this);
                }
            }
        }

        if (this.getIsCritical())
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                this.worldObj.spawnParticle(EnumParticleTypes.CRIT, this.posX + this.motionX * (double)i / 4.0D, this.posY + this.motionY * (double)i / 4.0D, this.posZ + this.motionZ * (double)i / 4.0D, -this.motionX, -this.motionY + 0.2D, -this.motionZ, new int[0]);
            }
        }

        this.posX += this.motionX;
        this.posY += this.motionY;
        this.posZ += this.motionZ;
        f2 = MathHelper.sqrt_double(this.motionX * this.motionX + this.motionZ * this.motionZ);
        this.rotationYaw = (float)(Math.atan2(this.motionX, this.motionZ) * 180.0D / Math.PI);

        for (this.rotationPitch = (float)(Math.atan2(this.motionY, (double)f2) * 180.0D / Math.PI); this.rotationPitch - this.prevRotationPitch < -180.0F; this.prevRotationPitch -= 360.0F)
        {
            ;
        }

        while (this.rotationPitch - this.prevRotationPitch >= 180.0F)
        {
            this.prevRotationPitch += 360.0F;
        }

        while (this.rotationYaw - this.prevRotationYaw < -180.0F)
        {
            this.prevRotationYaw -= 360.0F;
        }

        while (this.rotationYaw - this.prevRotationYaw >= 180.0F)
        {
            this.prevRotationYaw += 360.0F;
        }

        this.rotationPitch = this.prevRotationPitch + (this.rotationPitch - this.prevRotationPitch) * 0.2F;
        this.rotationYaw = this.prevRotationYaw + (this.rotationYaw - this.prevRotationYaw) * 0.2F;
        f3 = 0.99F;
        f1 = 0.05F;
    }
```

Declaration in onItemRightClick() in crossbow:

```
   float f = (float)j / 20.0F;
            f = (f * f + f * 2.0F) / 3.0F;

            if ((double)f < 0.1D)
            {
                return stack;
            }

            if (f > 1.0F)
            {
                f = 1.0F;
            }

            EntityFlingArrow entityarrow = new EntityFlingArrow(world, player, f * 2.0F);
```

Comment: Are you spawning the arrow on the player location or 1 block in the facing direction away, if the former then it is hitting the player on spawn

Answer (score 1):

Get the bounding box of the player, and make sure you spawn the arrow OUTSIDE of that box. the moment the bounding box of your entity and the player collide it's a hit.

This can even be on spawn of your entity, because they they'll intersect.

Take a look at the code of the normal bow and arrow or snowballs, how they determine the spawning. Then adjust for the bounding box size of your entity.